# Java access Thread's class attributes

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm building a console game in Java that works like this: It prints you an operation (e.g: 3 x 4) and you must write the result (12 in this case), and it will give you operations during a period of 1 minute and then it will finish.

I knew from the beginning I had to use threads to catch the user input, so this is the thread's logic:

```
public class UserInput extends Thread {

    private int answer;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(true){
            answer = in.nextInt();
        }
    }

    public int getAnswer(){
        return answer;
    }
}
```

quite simple, now the game's logic:

```
public static void play() {

    Game game = new EasyGame();     
    UserInput ui = new UserInput();     
    long beginTime = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;

    ui.start();     
    boolean accepted = true;

    while(timeLeft(beginTime)){
        //PrintChallenge() prints an operation and store its result in game
        if(accepted) game.PrintChallenge();
        accepted = false;           
        if(ui.getAnswer() == game.getResult()) accepted = true;     
    }
}

//returns if current time is 60 seconds after initial time
public static boolean timeLeft(long time){      
    return (System.currentTimeMillis()/1000) < (time + 60);
}
```

but it isn't working, it simply never matches ui's `getAnswer()` with game's `getResult()`. What am I doing wrong on this thread and game logics?

Comment: what's game.getResult() doing?

Comment: when method PrintChallenge() runs, it prints a challenge on the screen ("3x4" for example) and stores the result of this challenge into a variable, then game.getResult() returns this variable's value

Comment: Try to print `game.getResult()`.

Comment: Set a breakpoint at the `if` statement and check the result of `ui.getAnswer()` and `game.getResult()`. That will help you figure out where the bug is. Also keep in mind that Java may add some "performance tricks" that introduce bugs. To ensure that a value is always read from memory (instead of performing those tricks) add the `volatile` keyword to the `answer` attribute of `UserInput`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is Java caching the value of your int locally, though it could be due to something in your game.getResult(), since I cannot check this. Thread safety is difficult in java.

To confirm:

- I built a dumb version of the game, without any game logic or timer.
- I added a volatile keyoword to your answer int, this makes Java check main memory rather than local cache for the value of the int.

The following code outputs once the user enters "30", removing the "volatile" keyoword in user input leads to your situation.

See below:

```
package stackOverflowTests;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class simpleGame {
    public static class UserInput extends Thread {

        volatile private int answer;

        public void run() {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            while(true){
                System.out.print("Answer meeee!:");
                answer = in.nextInt();
            }
        }

        public int getAnswer(){
            return answer;
        }
    }
    public static void play() throws InterruptedException {

        UserInput testInput = new UserInput();
        testInput.start();
        while(true){
            //PrintChallenge() prints an operation and store its result on game
            Thread.sleep(10);
            if(testInput.getAnswer()==30)System.out.println(testInput.getAnswer()+ " : "+(testInput.getAnswer()==10));
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException{
        play();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 private int answer;
```

This variable needs to be `volatile`, as you are reading and writing it from different threads. Or else you need to synchronize all access to it, both reads and writes.